# Enforce a space group on a given crystal structure

Tags: software, space-groups, crystal-structure

If I have a CIF that is P1, is there a (preferably free) code that can map the structure to some user-specified space group? I know that there are ways to do similar things with molecular systems. For instance, [ChemCraft](http://www.chemcraftprog.com/) has an option to detect the nearest point group and then apply it to the molecule. I'd like to do the same for a crystalline structure given a space group.

Comment: Do you mean, identifying underlying symmetry of the crystal?

Comment: I primarily mean updating the atomic positions to fit a given space group. While it'd be nice if the code can detect the closest symmetry, that is not a requirement. For instance, let's say you have a DFT-optimized structure. It'll probably have no symmetry unless the tolerances to detect the symmetry are somewhat loose. Are there codes that could map the structure to match a given symmetry?

Comment: As an aside, I know this can be done in Materials Studio, but that's paid software. For context to my question, my machine with Materials Studio is in lab, which I can't access because of the global pandemic, so I'm looking for an alternative...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done using [PyMOL](https://pymol.org/2/) (which, while not free for general use, does have a free student license) via the `set_symmetry` argument, as documented [here](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Set_Symmetry). This allows for a user-specified spacegroup and will update the CIF to match.

Comment: PyMOL also has Open Source version, which is free for all users and has `set_symmetry`.

Answer (score 25):

While there are undoubtedly other programs that do this, it's fairly easy to do in Avogadro.

- I start with a calculation on hexagonal SiC. As mentioned, it starts as $P_1$:

[image: triclinic setting of a non-ideal SiC unit cell]

- Go to Crystallography -> Space Group -> Perceive Space Group

[image: Avogadro menu item for Perceive Space Group...]

- The unit cell should update, including symmetrization if needed

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! I admit... I am feeling quite silly that I didn't realize this! I'll keep the question unanswered for now so others feel inclined to comment too.

Comment: It's a fairly common task - I don't know other materials builders well, but I suspect others can do this.

Comment: Since I was curious, just for completeness: like ASE below, avogadro [actually also uses spglib to achieve this](https://github.com/OpenChemistry/avogadrolibs/blob/1925ee1dd6e33d1130167fd2faecaaf98c2f29e0/avogadro/core/avospglib.h#L47), specifically [`spg_get_dataset`](https://spglib.github.io/spglib/api.html#spg-get-dataset-and-spg-get-dataset-with-hall-number)

Answer (score 8):

This is possible via [ASE](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/index.html) as well.  There are modules which can handle space groups via [spglib](https://spglib.github.io/spglib/).  I will focus on an application that hasn't been discussed yet.

ASE has an advantage that you can [enforce symmetry](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/constraints.html?highlight=strain%20filter#the-fixsymmetry-class) during an optimization of cell size / positions.  Here is an example that can be run with [GPAW](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/index.html) which will load a geometry (`POSCAR`) and optimize the cell size and shape while keeping the original symmetry.

```
from ase.io import read
from ase.optimize.bfgs import BFGS
from ase.constraints import UnitCellFilter
from ase.spacegroup.symmetrize import FixSymmetry
from gpaw import GPAW, PW

atoms = read("POSCAR")
atoms.set_constraint(FixSymmetry(atoms))

si.calc = GPAW(xc='PBE',
               mode=PW(400, dedecut='estimate'),
               kpts=(4, 4, 4),
               txt='stress.txt')

uf = UnitCellFilter(si)
relax = BFGS(uf)
relax.run(fmax=0.05)
```

The full trajectory will be contained in `stress.txt`.  [Other calculators that ASE supports](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/index.html#supported-calculators) can be used by simply changing the GPAW based lines to another calculator.  It will need to implement a stress tensor though, so this restricts use somewhat.  For example, GPAW does not support stress tensor calculations in FD or LCAO modes currently.